# Export list of mails in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, export

I need to share info of my mailbox. That is, I need to send somebody the contents of what I have in a particular folder. But *not* the content itself, just an overview of the mails. Best would be the same info as what I can see when looking at the folder (Sender, time, subject, etc), but in a text format (plain text/CVS/something_similar)

When I look for this I just get results about exporting mails, but I only want to export the meta data, so to speak. Is this doable?

Answer (score 10):

Check out the [ImportExportTools NG](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/) extension for Thunderbird.  It has many additional import and export functions, including what sounds to be what you're looking for:

> - Export indexes as plain text or CSV

Comment: Here’s the direct link to Mozilla’s add-on site: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/

Comment: For newer versions of Thunderbird, it's ImportExportTools NG: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/