# Thunderbird: export a mailing list thread to HTML or plain text

Tags: thunderbird, html, export, mailing-lists, plaintext

Howto export a mailing list thread to HTML or plain text. Thread have 40+ mails. I use OS X if that matters.

[image]

export should be well formatted and readable

Answer (score 4):

The [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) add-on can export all messages in a folder as a single text file, a series of html files with an html index, or a series of individual files (.eml, .txt, html). Works well on Windows, don't know about Mac.

Found by way of the related [Export list of mails in Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/330458/export-list-of-mails-in-thunderbird)